Fill in sloping yard against wood fence
My backyard slopes almost 20 inches backing up to a pressure treated wood fence. I want to level the yard, so I need to fill the slope by the fence. I know I cannot even simply pile dirt against fence. the other side of fence faces outward to a public area, so I cannot cut it shorter. My idea was to create a retaining wall facing the fence, then fill in behind the wall thereby levelling my yard. My main question is there will be a pretty big gap between the wall and the fence. What can I fill that with? gravel? If I leave it open it will certainly fill with leaves and debris and defeat the purpose of the wall.

What is the length of the back fence that you would fill against? What is the height of the fence above the current soil level in your backyard and above the soil level in the public area outside? Does the same type of fence continue on the perpendicular sides? Is the fence a uniform height that follows the grade or is the top of the fence level so that the height of the fence varies with grade?

the fence is 6 feet above the grade line, and it is a new fence that goes uniformly around my property, so removing it is not an option. my backyard originally just sloped down into a retaining pond. I put up the fence along my property line. so on the public face it continues to slope.  It is a 6 foot fence everywhere around the sides & back of my house, except for about 18 feet where it is actually 8 feet to make up for the slope.

Why would you pile dirt against the fence?  Wouldn't that only increase the slope?

If it's a new fence and you didn't plan and build the retaining wall first, that's a planning failure with an incorrect order of operations. You can remove and redo this part of it as suggested in an answer, or you can choose some less-functional and more prone-to-fail option.

well,  Ecnerwal, thank you for you snide and not at all helpful comment.

Huesmann - the yard slopes down toward a retaining pond. I needed a fence for the dogs and kids. now that we have been in the home a couple of years, I was looking to level the yard. Yes, I wish my "way-back machine" was working, but I cannot time travel, so I am looking for helpful ideas.

I did just check with our HOA (which I will never buy a house with a HOA again) I am not allowed to build a retaining wall facing the public pond. (they call it a pond, but it is a dirty run-off pond) so I cannot cut or re-do the fence. So I am back to trying to build a retaining wall behind the fence (on my side) to allow for a level yard. I am still concerned about the gap between the wall and the fence.

If you do not want a gap between the fence and the retaining wall then the best fix for that is to:

Remove the existing fence.
Build the retaining wall such that its public facing side is aligned where the existing fence was located.
Build a replacement fence on top of the retaining wall.

Some possibilities to consider:

Use concrete for the retaining wall.
Make sure to provide a suitable footing below the retaining wall to alleviate frost problems.
Use rebar in both the footing and retaining wall.
Consider using metal posting for the replacement fence that is embedded into the concrete retaining wall. This will make a far more sturdy fence than trying to affix the fence posts on top of the retaining wall.

